# O que significam os dois pontos seguidos (..) num caminho de arquivo?

Tags: css, url

Eu ainda não entendi o que isso significa. Por que eu devo colocar esses dois pontos?

Exemplo: `..\Images/Logo.png`

Comment: Na maioria das vezes, melhor evitar os `..` em ambiente de produção, a não ser que seu projeto precise ser hospedado em níveis diferentes dependendo da situação (se é uma aplicação separada do site principal, caminhos relativos ajudam na "portabilidade" entre pastas). O `..` é relativo à pasta atual. Se começar por `/caminho/desde/raiz`, os arquivos serão buscados sempre na mesma pasta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Projeto
   Images
      Logo.png
   CSS
      styles.css
```

Se você estiver dentro da pasta CSS usando o arquivo `style.css` e quer acessar uma imagem que está numa pasta no mesmo nível da pasta CSS você faz:

```
../Images/Logo.png
```

`..` significa **voltar** uma pasta ou um nível.

`../../` volta para pasta Projeto, ou a raiz, dependendo da sua estrutura.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigada!

Answer (score 10):

Imagine que você está numa estrutura assim:

```
/
 css
    estilo.css
 Images
    Logo.png
 Scripts
    ...
```

Ou seja, na raiz do projeto tem as pastas css, Imagens, Scripts, etc.
Se você quiser que o arquivo estilo.css acesse o arquivo Logo.png que está em outro pasta, os dois pontos seguidos (..) faz com que a referência seja a pasta acima de css (/) e em seguida Imagens.

Se usar no css "Imagens/Logo.png", significa que a pasta "Imagens" deveria estar dentro da pasta atual, que é CSS, a pasta do arquivo estilo.css.

Espero que tenha conseguido explicar.

Answer (score 7):

A denotação `..`  sobe um nível de pasta.

Por exemplo: Sua imagem, `Logo.png`, está na pasta `Images` e seu `arquivo.css` na pasta `CSS`. Você usa os dois pontos para "chegar" até a pasta `Images`.