# Servidor não busca folhas de estilos

Tags: html, css, http, servidor

tenho um site que gera os seguintes erros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda sobre isso? 
Esse site no Localhost (usando o xampp) funciona normalmente, não falta nada. Mas é só eu levar para o servidor que ele gera esses erros.

Segue código do header do index. (Para os que ficam pedindo código, o body não é importante, é apenas html5 comum sem nenhum outro recurso).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Mrig - Multi-purpose Template">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Mrig - Multi-purpose Template">
  <meta name="author" content="Mandy">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

  <title>SG - Papéis Especiais</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
   <!-- Bootstrap CSS File -->
  <link type="text/css" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Libraries CSS Files -->

  <link type="text/css" href="lib/lightbox/css/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Main Stylesheet File -->
  <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link type="text/css" href="static/plugin/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" href="static/plugin/font-awesome/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" href="static/plugin/et-line/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" href="static/plugin/themify-icons/themify-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" href="static/plugin/owl-carousel/css/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" href="static/plugin/magnific/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Start WOW Slider.com HEAD section -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="engine1/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- End WOW Slider.com HEAD section -->

    <link type="text/css" href="lib/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <link type="text/css" href="static/css/header.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" href="static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" href="static/css/color/default.css" rel="stylesheet" id="color_theme">

 <style>
 .fundoparallax{


  background-image: url(images/plano-de-fundo-parallax.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;

}
.product_view .modal-dialog{max-width: 800px; width: 100%;}
.fundo{


  background-image: url(images/contato-sg-papeis-especiais.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;

}
.f1 {


  background-image: url(images/sublimacao-de-estampas.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;

}
.f2 {


  background-image: url(images/banner-papeis-para-engenharia.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;

}
.f3 {


  background-image: url(images/outdoor-para-publicidade.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;

}
  ol {
  float:left;
}
* html li {margin-left:25px;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
}

.right {
  width: 75%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
</style>


<script>
 $(window).load(function(){        
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }); 

 $('form').on('submit', function(){

  $('.modal').modal('hide'); 

});

</script>


</head>


<body>

  <header class="header header-transparent header-style-02">
```

Alguem sabe o que se passa?

Comment: Você precisa mudar os links pra apontar para o servidor... Ex: `<link type="text/css" href="http://www.NOMEDOSITE.com/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Deve ser algum .htaccess no seu servidor.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não tem não.

Comment: @gustavox vlw, resolvido... Agradeço brow

Comment: @LougansdeMatos manda o link

Comment: não quer passar essa resposta pro principal pra eu marcar como correta! AHUSEHAU

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que significam os dois pontos seguidos (..) num caminho de arquivo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162058/o-que-significam-os-dois-pontos-seguidos-num-caminho-de-arquivo)

Comment: @LougansdeMatos acontece kkkk não vou por de resposta porque tem várias perguntas como essa aqui hehe.. boa sorte ae, abraço