# Background-image css3 não funcina

Tags: html5, css3, background-image

Bom dia pessoal,

estou tentando colocar uma imagem como background da minha página html mas não esta funcionando.

**Alguém saberia indicar qual o erro do meu código?**

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Pain Free</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Site voltado para manipular doencas de pacientes que utiizando o app do pain free">
    <meta name="Laura" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/registerPatient.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/menu.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>      
</head>

<body>

  <?php include ("class/menu.php"); ?>
        <!-------------------------------- FORMULARIO DE CADASTRO DE PACIENTE ----------------------------->
          <section id="register_patient">
              <div class="container_register_patient">
               <form  action="cadastro.php" method="POST">
               <label for="inputCity" class="title"><b>Informações Básicas</b></label>
                  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-5 ">
                      <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Nome Completo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                      <input type="text" name="cpf" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="CPF">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" style="border:3px solid green" placeholder="Email do Aplicativo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                      <input type="password" name="senha" class="form-control" style="border:3px solid green" placeholder="Senha do Aplicativo">
                    </div>
                  </div>
</div>
          </section>

<script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/fixed-responsive-nav.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**registerPatient.css**

```
@-webkit-viewport { width: device-width; }
@-moz-viewport { width: device-width; }
@-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }
@-o-viewport { width: device-width; }
@viewport { width: device-width; }

body
{
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("img/doctorBackground.jpg") !important;
}
/* ===================== CADASTRO DE PACIENTE ========================= */
#register_patient
{
    width: 45em;
    height: 56.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 6em;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;  
}

.container-register-patient
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: center;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

**print da organização das pastas**

[image: Print da organização das pastas]

Comment: Onde vc está carregando esse `index.css`?

Comment: Coloquei o nome da referência do arquivo errada na pergunta, vou editar.

Comment: Tenta `"./img/doctorBackground.jpg"`. Do jeito que está, a pasta `img` deveria estar dentro da pasta `/css`.

Comment: Seria interessante vc colocar uma imagem de como está a organização das suas pastas, tira um print ai do diretório aberto mostrando como está as pastas do projeto.

Comment: @Sam eu já tinha tentado dessa forma e continua sem funcionar.

Comment: Dá algum erro no console do navegador?

Comment: Aparece uns warnings no javascript, mas acredito que isso não influencia na parte do css.

Comment: Vai em inspecionar elementos do navegador e clique na tag "body" e veja as propriedades do CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu caminho está errado, sua estrutura de pasta está assim correto:

```
BACKOFFICE (Pasta do projeto)
  css
    > registerPatient.css
  img
    > doctorBackground.jpg
  index.php
```

Repare que o `.php` e as *pastas* estão na raiz...

Então vc tem que "sair" da pasta `css` usando o `../` no início do path da imagem, e depois entrar na pasta `img` e indexar a imagem. Então o caminho vai ficar assim:

```
../img/doctorBackground.jpg
```

Recomendo que leia isso: [O que significam os dois pontos seguidos (..) num caminho de arquivo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162058/o-que-significam-os-dois-pontos-seguidos-num-caminho-de-arquivo) e isso: [Caminho para acesso de pastas html ,css,php etc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198422/caminho-para-acesso-de-pastas-html-css-php-etc/198440)

---

**EDIT**

No seu `<head>` inverta a ordem de indexação dos `.css` repare que no seu documento primeiro vc indexa os seus "custom.css" como `registerPatient.css` e `menu.css` e só depois o `bootstrap.css`.

**Muito provavelmente o `bootstrap.css` está fazendo uma sobreposição de classes e tirando os estilos do `background` do `body`**. Então deixe a indexação dessa forma, pois pode ser que resolva o problema... Primeiro o CSS do Bootstrap, e só depois os seus `.css`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/registerPatient.css">
```

Comment: Coloquei os dois pontos e testei com e sem aspas, e ainda não funciona.

Comment: @LauraRegina não sei se tem a ver, mas isso não existe `width: device-width;` vc pode ver aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport que ele fala que é para vc declarar o *device-width* e não para usar *device-width* como valor do `width`... Veja na lista dos possíveis valores que não existe a opção de `device-width`, apenas min-width, 
max-width e width. Eu testei seu código aqui com `background-image: url("https://placecage.com/100/100") !important;` e funcionou! http://prntscr.com/njxlk0

Comment: @LauraRegina leia o **EDIT** que coloquei na resposta, isso deve resolver o problema!

Comment: @hugocsi eu **não** estou usando **background-image: url("https://placecage.com/100/100") !important;** estou utilizando **background-image: url("../img/doctorBackground.jpg");**

Comment: O erro foi o combo da ordem da chamada do css, a sintaxe de como eu estava buscando a imagem nos diretórios e por fim percebi que renomeei o arquivo e não lembrava disso (descobri isso no inspetor do navegador, pois informava que não estava encontrando o arquivo, então fui comparar o nome que mostrou no navegador com o nome que estava na pasta do servidor). Obrigada a todos pela ajuda!

Comment: @LauraRegina que bom que resolveu, o teste do CSS que fiz foi apenas uma questão de eliminar possibilidades de onde o erro estaria, e testando com um link de imagem externa já eliminaria o erro no CSS. Mas legal que resolveu! 