# php mvc import css file

Tags: php, css, mvc, back-end

olá estou fazendo um sistema com a estrutura mvc, essa é a estrutura de pastas:

```
MVC
    controller
        home.php
    core
        core.php
    public
        css
            cssFiles.css
    views
        home.php
    .htaccess
    index.php
```

Bom o codigo funciona assim, primeiro a index.php cria um objeto core (que gerencia as url), e chama o controler/home.php. o home.php renderiza a view/home.php, mas as imagens, css e js. Não são encontrados como posso resolver isso?

Comment: *"mas as imagens, css e js não são encontrados"* só colocar o caminho correto. Pela estrutura que desenhou, por exemplo na "home.php" para carregar o css precisar do caminho `"../public/css/cssFiles.css"` e assim por diante. Coloque o código da página para ficar mais fácil, e tbm onde ficam as imagens? Tem essa pergunta que explica isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/162063/57220

Comment: Ja fiz esse teste e nada.